# quarkus:add extension custom extensions

Tags: quarkus

for the command
./mvnw quarkus:add-extension -Dextensions=“name”

is it possible to add  custom extensions？ I tired create my own, but when I executed the above command, it always failed,

is it the fact that I can only add the extensions from the results
./mvnw quarkus:list-extensions

Answer (score 2):

Unless the extension is present in the Quarkus extension registry, that command will work only if you provide the complete GAV in place of "name" in the format groupId:artifactId:version

Otherwise, the tools won't be able to resolve the extension, i.e. to translate the "name" to the actual GAV that should be added to your project as a dependency.

Luckily, the Quarkus team is developing a mechanism to be able to register Quarkus extensions such as yours and make them discoverable by the Quarkus tools. You can read more about it here https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkiverse/wiki

Answer (score 0):

If your extension is not in the catalog/platform you need to use the full maven coordinate of your extension.